# "Enable Just My Code" in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

Is there a way to debug external cpp code in Visual Studio C++ 6.0? I mean, cpp code that is pre-compiled and linked to (but not compiled in) the solution. In newer versions (e.g. Visual Studio 2008 and later) I just put the code among the project files and it works, if "Enable Just My Code" is un-ckecked.I don't find anything like this for the older Visual C++ 6.0 version...

Comment: I do remember stepping "into" the MFC quite often, so it was definitely the default. But that thing is almost 20 years old... I have colleagues that are younger than that compiler. Maybe get a newer compiler?

Comment: ah, ah. You are right. I use it as it is the one used for this old project I'm working on. It is used as a standard in the platform I'm updating. Maybe I may try to import it on a new Visual Stuido without too many problems? Will give it a try...

Comment: @hank7v, VC++6.0 was really old, actually we also didn't support it. If possible, you could test it using the latest VS version and developing language. See http://codexpert.ro/blog/2016/04/10/visual-studio-2015-how-to-step-into-mfc-framework-code/

Comment: Thanks, useful link indeed, as I also work on last VS versions projects luckily...